# Audio source: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: html, audio

I have an audio source like so:

```
<audio>
    <source crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://c5.rbxcdn.com/978fe05256c23450b0c55c271ff9df58" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

But it never loads, and this is shown in the console:
`GET https://c5.rbxcdn.com/978fe05256c23450b0c55c271ff9df58 net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`

Any idea? Doing a normal fetch() works fine with no cors errors or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work in `video` tag

```html
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
<source src="https://c5.rbxcdn.com/978fe05256c23450b0c55c271ff9df58" type="audio/mpeg">
</video>
```